# Why can't I get pandas to show my list of lists correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list containing lists of strings. I want to visualize it in a way tat each value unique to a certain list has a highlighted background. I can not get, however, pandas to show my list of lists as a dataframe, it just prints the following:

```
            0
0  [s1, s2, s3]
1          [s1]
```

Just to clarify, this is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(strings_lists)

df.style.applymap(color_unique_secrets)

print(df)
```

And the function I'm trying to apply:

```
def color_unique_strings(val):
  if not val:
    return 'background-color: black;'
  for d in diff: # diff == a  list of lists of unique strings in a database
    if bal in d:
      return 'background-color: yellow;'
  return 'background-color: white;'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be that you’re looking at the dataframe instead of the `df.style` object: when you set styles, it doesn’t modify the dataframe, only the `df.style` object. This keeps data and formatting separated.

Also, when you do `print(df)` you’re rendering the dataframe as plain text. This means no colours can be applied. Instead, you need to pick a format that is supported by the `Styler` object returned by [`df.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html):

- as html, with [`Styler.render()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html), or
- to excel with [`Styler.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html).

```
>>> style = df.style.applymap(color_unique_secrets)
>>> style.render()
'<style type="text/css">\n#T_fb2b6_row0_col0 {\n  background-color: yellow;\n}\n#T_fb2b6_row1_col0 {\n  background-color: white;\n}\n</style>\n<table id="T_fb2b6_">\n  <thead>\n    <tr>\n      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>\n      <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >0</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th id="T_fb2b6_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>\n      <td id="T_fb2b6_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >[\'s1\', \'s2\', \'s3\']</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th id="T_fb2b6_level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>\n      <td id="T_fb2b6_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >[\'s1\']</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n'
>>> with open('strings_lists.html', 'w') as f:
...     print(style.render(), file=f)
... 
>>> style.to_excel('strings_lists.xlsx')
```

Here’s what the html result looks like:
[image]

And here’s what the excel result looks like:
[image]

---

Just 2 cents on your function to make it more readable, you can aggregate the list of lists into a set to it make a simple lookup:

```
unique_strings = set.union(*map(set, diff))
```

Or:

```
unique_strings = set(sum(diff, []))
```

This makes the function more readable:

```
def color_unique_strings(val):
  if not val:
    return 'background-color: black;'
  if val in unique_strings:
    return 'background-color: yellow;'
  return 'background-color: white;'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to understand how did you declared the 'strings_lists'.

When I tried the following piece of code, your function 'color_unique_strings' was perfectly working on it

```
strings_lists = [["s1", "s2", "s3"], ["s1"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(strings_lists)
df
```

[image]

```
diff = ["s1", "s3"]

def color_unique_strings(val):
    if not val:
        return 'background-color: black;'
for d in diff: # diff == a  list of lists of unique strings in a database
    if val in d:
        return 'background-color: yellow;'
    return 'background-color: white;'

df.style.applymap(color_unique_strings)
```

[image]

Comment: To reproduce the dataframe you need `pd.DataFrame([[["s1", "s2", "s3"]], [["s1"]]])`

Comment: @Cimbali this will obviously lead the dataframe to be created incorrectly as it will consider it as a 3d list.

Comment: you should try it first, it does work. It’s a 2D array of list objects, if you prefer. `np.array([[["s1", "s2", "s3"]], [["s1"]]], dtype='object')` also works.

Comment: What you got was exactly to what I wanted to get, but couldn't. It needed a restart.